# Azure Container Instances: static private ip

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I'm deploying several ACI's with yml and included private ip:

```
 osType: Linux
 ipAddress:
      type: Private
      ip: 10.0.2.6
      ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        port: 80
      - protocol: tcp
        port: 30810
```

But my container does not always get the same ip. Sometimes it gets `10.0.2.4` or `10.0.2.5`. Is there any way I can configure, that it always gets the same ip in Virtual network?